# Is this concept possible with iOS navigation tools

Tags: ios, core-location

Lets say we have a starting point, (x,y). By using iOS navigation can we tell how far from that starting point we moved to another location (a,b). So if i walked 20 feet in a certain direction after starting would it be able to tell me how far I've moved and in which direction?

If this technology exists can I get info on where to start learning about it?

This also needs to be done without GPS, sorry.

Comment: GPS can't necessarily detect small changes.  I'm not sure whether or not 20 feet is a big enough change for GPS to accurately detect.

Comment: Yes sorry, @rmaddy i meant to include without using gps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't determine location changes accurately without GPS, even with GPS it is difficult to accuracy measure position change as small as 20 feet (GPS 5m accuracy means a +/-15 foot error)

In theory you might be able to write software to create an [Internal Navigation System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_navigation_system) using the built in accelerometers, gyros, and magnetometers, but in practice they are too noisy and have too much error for this kind of use (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10843615/1693173)).  A better rocket scientist than me might be able to make it work but it was also need to use the GPS to keep it from drifting.  The M7 chip on the 5S might make this feasible.

Answer (score 1):

As rmaddy mentioned With core location class and incorporating GPS in a project you can obtain a distance traveled by the person who is walking. I found a great step by step tutorial for you which has a sample project you can build and take a look at. Here is the link..http://www.perspecdev.com/blog/2012/02/22/using-corelocation-on-ios-to-track-a-users-distance-and-speed/

Also here is the link to core location class reference for further study....https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html